# To find a $y_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I need to prove this theorem for **positive series**:

> $\forall {x_n}$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_n$ diverges, $\exists y_n$ such that:
>   1) $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} y_n$ also diverges.
>   2) $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{y_n}{x_n}=0$.

I believe that it may have something to do with the **comparison test** (in a limit form), but since $x_n$ is implicit, I really don't know where to start to construct an even "smaller" $y_n$ that diverges. Any answer or hint will be appreciated. Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the first $a_1$ numbers sum to more than 1.
Let the next $a_2$ numbers sum to more than 2.
Let the next $a_3$ numbers sum to more than 3.
Divide the first $a_1$ numbers by 1.  They add up to more than 1.
Divide the next $a_2$ numbers by 2.   They still add up to more than 1.
Total $\geq1+1+1+...$

Comment: So do you mean that $$y_n=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{a_n}x_i}{n}$$? And if so, how to show that $\lim \frac {y_n}{x_n}=0$?

Comment: Well, if $y_n$ is like this, then I don't think $\frac {y_n}{x_n}\to 0$ will always hold. Let's take $x_n=\frac1n$ for example, surely it is quite easy to construct such a $y_n$, but since $y_n>1$ and $x_n\to 0$, $\frac{y_n}{x_n}$ simply blows up... so I'm afraid your $y_n$ doesn't meet the second requirement.

Comment: $1\geq 1,\frac12+\frac13+...+\frac1{11}>2$, so do $1/1,(\frac12)/2,(\frac13)/2,...,(\frac1{11})/2,(\frac1{12})/3,...$

Comment: $y_n=x_n/m$, where $m$ is slowly increasing.

Comment: Oh exactly! I'm stupid and it seems like I have misunderstood part of your answer, really sorry for that. And Thank you very much for all your help and explanations!